# having an issue about the output in c programming ..

Tags: c, codeblocks

i'm having a problem on running the output after putting the input..
the output doesn't show after i put the variables and i don't know how to set the code ..
so if you guys could help me with this, that would be grateful..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int read_temps (float temps[]);
int hot_days (int numOfTemp, float temps[]);
int printf_temps (int numOfTemp, float temps[], int numOfHotDays);

int main (void) {
int index = 0;
float tempVal;
float temps[31];
int numOfTemp, numOfHotDays;

do {
    printf ("Enter the temperature:");
    scanf ("%f", &tempVal);
    if (tempVal!=-500.0) {
        temps[index] = tempVal;
        index++;
    }
} while (tempVal != -500.0);

return ;

{
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numOfTemp; i++) {
        if (temps[i] > 32.0)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

{
    float sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    printf ("\nInput Temperatures:");
    printf ("\n-------------------------");

    for (i = 0;i < numOfTemp; i++) {
        printf ("\nDay %d : %.2fF", i+1, temps[i]);
        sum = sum + temps[i];
    }
    printf ("\nNumber of Hot Days : %d", numOfHotDays);
    printf ("\nAverage Temperature: %.2f", sum/numOfTemp);
}

{
    clrscr ();
    numOfTemp = read_temps (temps);
    numOfHotDays = hot_days (numOfTemp, temps);
    clrscr ();
    printf_temps (numOfTemp, temps, numOfHotDays);
    getch ();
}
}
```

Comment: this is the main task for this code ..

Comment: As part of a global warming analysis, a research facility tracks outdoor temperatures at the North Pole once a day, at noon, for a year.
At the end of each month, these temperatures are entered into the computer and processed. The operator will enter 28, 29, 30, or 31 data items, depending on the month.
You may use 500 as a sentinel value after the last temperature, since that is lower than absolute 0. #1

Comment: Your main program should call the read_temps(), hot_days(), and print_temps() functions described here:
(b) Write a function, read_temps(), that has one parameter, an array called temps, in which to store the temperatures. Read the real data values for one month and store them into the slots of an array. #2

Comment: Return the actual number of temperatures read as the result of the function.
(c) Write a function, hot_days(), that has two parameters: the number of temperatures for the current month and an array in which the temperatures are stored. Search through the temperature array and count all the days on which the noon temperature exceeds 32 F. Return this count.
(d) Write a function, print_temps(), with the same two parameters plus the count of hot days. Print a neat table of temperatures. At the same time,#3

Comment: calculate the average temperature for the month and print it at the end of the table, followed by the number of hot days.#4

Answer (score 3):

```
 return ;
```

You just told your function to stop executing.

It's doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: i know that this is the problem.. the thing is i don't know how to fix it !!

Answer (score 2):

That's actually a good effort. You have the code logic done perfectly, it's just that they're not arranged correctly.

You have the sub-functions that you want to call from `main` embedded within their own scope *within `main` itself.* That's not going to work well.

What you need to do is to first move them outside of `main` and add their declaration lines. Then you need to call them from `main`. In other words, something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_temps (float temps[]);
int hot_days (int numOfTemp, float temps[]);
int printf_temps (int numOfTemp, float temps[], int numOfHotDays);

int main (void) {
    int index = 0;
    float temps[31];
    int numOfTemp, numOfHotDays;

    // The code to call them has been cleaned up.

    numOfTemp = read_temps (temps);
    numOfHotDays = hot_days (numOfTemp, temps);
    printf_temps (numOfTemp, temps, numOfHotDays);

    return 0;
}

// All the functions that were subsumed in main
//   have been separated and properly defined here.

int hot_days (int numOfTemp, float temps[]) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < numOfTemp; i++) {
        if (temps[i] > 32.0)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int printf_temps (int numOfTemp, float temps[], int numOfHotDays) {
    float sum = 0.0;
    int i;
    printf ("\nInput Temperatures:");
    printf ("\n-------------------------");

    for (i = 0;i < numOfTemp; i++) {
        printf ("\nDay %d : %.2fF", i+1, temps[i]);
        sum = sum + temps[i];
    }
    printf ("\nNumber of Hot Days : %d", numOfHotDays);
    printf ("\nAverage Temperature: %.2f\n", sum/numOfTemp);
}

int read_temps (float temps[]) {
    int index = 0;
    float tempVal;
    do {
        printf ("Enter the temperature:");
        scanf ("%f", &tempVal);
        if (tempVal!=-500.0) {
            temps[index] = tempVal;
            index++;
        }
    } while (tempVal != -500.0);
    return index;
}
```

I've basically performed the following steps:

- Removed the non-standard stuff like `conio`.
- Moved the embedded functions out to their proper place and given them the prototypes.
- Move some variables from `main` to the other functions where they belong.
- Tidied up some minor output things.
- Tested it :-)

The transcript below shows a sample run:

```
Enter the temperature:3
Enter the temperature:4
Enter the temperature:5
Enter the temperature:6
Enter the temperature:50
Enter the temperature:-500

Input Temperatures:
-------------------------
Day 1 : 3.00F
Day 2 : 4.00F
Day 3 : 5.00F
Day 4 : 6.00F
Day 5 : 50.00F
Number of Hot Days : 1
Average Temperature: 13.60
```

Answer (score 1):

And you should not return nothing in function main()

Comment: Because the function main() has a signature "int main()", in which "int" means "main" must return an integer somewhere (but no in the middle of the function like yours). And actually the conventional signature of main() is "int main(int argc, char** argv)". The book "The C Programming Language" will make you comfortable with C

Answer (score 0):

You have used `return;` before the function ends.
That will create **dead code**, and so function will not work as expected.

Comment: then where should i put it ?

Comment: you need not to put return because you are not returning anything from main method. so there no requirement of that return in main method.

Comment: @user2985811: Put a `return 0` at the very end of `main()`.